# AWS CodeDeploy 2 ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am using CodeDelpoy to deploy to an ASG, and it is working very well, but I ran to two issues.

When using the blue/green mode, I have noticed that there is a time where both my ASG are online, and when I refresh my LB address, I get both ASG's.
Another issue I have, is more of a question, is there anyway of defining the ASG new name?

thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to custom define the new ASG name for a blue green deployment. CodeDeploy creates the ASG with a random name which comes with a defined prefix. As for the second question, during a blue green deployment, at first CodeDeploy provisions a new ASG, deploys the new application revision to this new ASG, registers it behind the load balancer and then deregisters the old ASG from the loadbalancer and terminates it if selected. So yes at one point there will be both the old and new ASG instances behind the load balancer but they have different versions of the application running on them.

Comment: Thanks for the help first of all.
So do you have any solution for my main problem.
I do not wish that there will be two versions of my software up in the air at the same time.
Its around 2 minutes, and it could be critical.